# Trying to display a single product from a table products on a description page, but got the message" Trying to get property of non-object "

Tags: php

I'm trying to display a particular product on a "description" page that comes from a products page if this makes sense, but all I get is this error  "Trying to get property of non-object" so all I want is to get the selected product from a products page and display it in a description page... here is the code that I've used in my "more info" page, which is where the error is coming from, line 18*
Just clarify that the imagename is a field from my table that contains the covers which are the link for the more info pages.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "dbconn.php";

$productImage = $_GET['imagename'];

$Imagename = $productImage;


$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE imagename =".$productImage;

$results = $connect->query($query);


if ($results->num_rows != 1)//Line 18
die ("Database did not return one result");
else
{
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess `imagename` is a string, so it needs quotes around it.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE imagename = ' $productImage ' ";

$results = $connect->query($query);

if (!$results) die("error");
```

Comment: umm cool, I tried use the quotes but the error now is "Database did not return one result" :( but thanks anyway man!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to create the object $result like:

$result = new Something();

I suppose you created a class inside your "dbconn.php"...

Comment: you mean $results = $connect->query($query); ? sorry guys for the stupid questions is just because I'm really new to all this and...